# How to use a Thread for neworking operations

Tags: android, multithreading

I have this function which does network operations.. (i.e post data into a webpage)..But I am getting android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException..
I understood that I have to use the networking operations on a Thread but I have no Idea how to do that...Could u guys please help me with my code..
Thanks in advance.....
Here is my method

```
     public static String excutePost(String targetURL, String urlParameters)
{
  URL url;
  HttpURLConnection connection = null;  
  try {


    //Create connection
      url = new URL(targetURL);
      connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
      connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
      connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", 
           "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

      connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + 
               Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
      connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");  

      connection.setUseCaches (false);
      connection.setDoInput(true);
      connection.setDoOutput(true);

      //Send request
      DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
                  connection.getOutputStream ());
      wr.writeBytes (urlParameters);
      wr.flush ();
      wr.close ();

      //Get Response    
      InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
      String line;
      StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer(); 
      while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(line);
        response.append('\r');
      }
      rd.close();
      return response.toString();

  } catch (Exception e) {

   String g=e.toString();
  Log.d("errererer", g);
    return null;

  } finally {

    if(connection != null) {
      connection.disconnect(); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use AsyncTask for that. Check this link http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-tw/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private class AsyncCaller extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(AsyncExample.this);

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    //this method will be running on UI thread
    pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
    pdLoading.show();
}
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    //this method will be running on background thread so don't update UI      
      frome here
    //do your long running http tasks here,you dont want to pass argument 
    //and u can access the parent class' variable url over here
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    //this method will be running on UI thread

    pdLoading.dismiss();
}

}
}
```

and in oncreate() call this as-

```
new AsyncCaller().execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Thread or Asynctask

Invoke asynctask

```
  new TheTask().execute("http://192.168.1.88/androidtesting.php");
```

AsyncTask

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

```
class TheTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
    {

@Override
protected String onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    // update textview here
    textView.setText("Server message is "+result);
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
     try
        {
           excutePost(String targetURL, String urlParameters);
         }
         catch(Exception e){
             return "Network problem";
         }

}
}
```